# Why am I seeing 'blisque.mydomain.com' in my analytics?

Tags: domains, google-analytics, subdomain

When looking through my Google Analytics reports, I see visits via mydomain.com but also '**blisque.mydomain.com**'. When I visit there, the site is served up, however I haven't configured this subdomain myself, nor do I know what it is.

Any idea what this is??

Edit: I understand technically why this happening (through the wildcard DNS entry). **I'm more asking what 'blisque' is. Any idea?**

Answer (score 4):

Check to see if your base website returns using any combination of subdomain.

**Example: pigeon.mydomain.com**

If your server returns your base website using any/all subdomains then someone has probably linked to you using blisque.mydomain.com and that's why you see it.

I've seen the process of returning the normal site on all subdomains called "Wildcard Catchall Subdomains". A search with that term will likely return all you need to know about wildcard sudomains.

Answer (score 0):

My guess because of the limited information given here is that it's just a bot.